# Visual Studio CLONE ISSUE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-community

I am trying to clone the project from team explorer, the project gets cloned but with only git files. No project files are cloned with it. What could I have done wrong, please guide....

Comment: It's not uncommon to exclude IDE-specific files from a GIT repository. You may have to set up the project in Visual Studio yourself. Are you sure the repository is supposed to contain Visual Studio project files?

Comment: Yes I am sure of that, because last time when I cloned it, it had all the project files and codes. But this time it is cloning only 65 MB of the 4000 MB and saying cloned successful.